sphinx docstrings and vscode
I have the following docstring:
def test(foo):
    """this is my function
    
    .. code-block:: python
        cool function
    
    now I should be outside the codeblock. 
    But I'm not?
    
    .. code-block:: python
        next function
        
    I'm still inside the original codeblock?

    :param foo: _description_
    :type foo: _type_
    """

Which renders like this in VScode:

Am I writing the syntax incorrectly, or does VScode simply struggle with the rendering of sphinx format?


Which style of docstrings are you intending to use? 2) I think there has to be a blank line after a code block directive.



I'm using reStructuredText (Sphinx) style in order to create documentation in Sphinx later on. 2) I tried adding a blank line which doesn't help.


Got it.  There are two primary docstring styles; reST is the general sub-language that the Sphinx application uses to generate docs.    Google style, and numpy style.  Choose one, don’t mix.  There are good docstring examples in the links. Additionally, you might have to tell VSC which style to expect.  (I use Spyder, and there is an option for docstring style.)

And, as you might be aware, there is PEP-257 which outlines docstring styles, at a Python level.

As far as I can tell, I'm not mixing styles, but sticking to the style sphinx prescribes?
https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html
Also, I believe I have told VSC that I'm using Sphinx style:
https://i.imgur.com/ak1cxCR.png

What is your desired effect? Where do you think it is a misrepresentation?

I've managed to make proper sphinx documentation now, and the html output from sphinx looks good. However, VScode still renders it incorrectly. Please see this picture for further explanation: https://imgur.com/a/4uiMYTk
I believe the code-blocks should be exitted upon unindentation.

AFAIK Visual Studio Code cannot do this without additional plugin, or at least I have never seen it been able to do this. PyCharm, an alternative IDE, does somewhat better here.

There are two ways to get the display right
1. Add a level of indentation for code blocks
def test(foo):
    """this is my function
    
        .. code-block:: python
        cool function
    
    now I should be outside the codeblock. 
    But I'm not?
    
        .. code-block:: python
        next function
        
    I'm still inside the original codeblock?

    :param foo: _description_
    :type foo: _type_
    """


2. Remove one level of indentation for non-code blocks
def test(foo):
    """this is my function
    
    .. code-block:: python
        cool function
    
now I should be outside the codeblock. 
But I'm not?
    
    .. code-block:: python
        next function
        
I'm still inside the original codeblock?

    :param foo: _description_
    :type foo: _type_
    """


I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax, or if it's a vscode error. If anyone thinks it's an error, you can report it on GitHub and share the link here.

That's incorrect restructured text syntax. I think Visual Studio Code here is assuming Markdown.

I'm not sure if there is a syntax error here in the language but your 2. suggestion works like a charm! I get a good looking vscode rendering and sphinx also builds the html with correct code-blocks and indentations. Thank you very much
